# @Input not working on Angular

Tags: angular

EDIT : as requested I made a plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/6rUQdBFFSqNMTojARFXZ

I'm trying to make the `@Input` decorator work with two simple components. The parent component is this one:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { SidebarComponent } from './components/sidebar.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<sidebar [sidebarSize]="menu_size"></sidebar>'
})

export class AppComponent {
  menu_size: string = '40';
}
```

It's supposed to contain the full view, within which we can find the following child component:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'sidebar',
  templateUrl: '<p>This is a sidebar {{sidebarSize}}</p>'
})

export class SidebarComponent {
  @Input('sidebarSize') sidebarSize:string;
}
```

When I try to execute this, I'm getting an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'sidebarSize' since it isn't a known native property ("<sidebar [ERROR ->][sidebarSize]="menu_size"></sidebar>")
```

Comment: Provide plunker (:

Comment: Looks ok to me, try a hard reset/refresh yet in your browser to make sure the latest is getting loaded?

Comment: First of all, I think you don't need to aliased your input : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/style-guide.html#05-13 Next try this : `<sidebar [menu_size]="sidebarSize"></sidebar>`

Comment: Plunker would be nice. Might be something missing in your module as it looks fine.

Comment: @mickdev -  `[menu_size]="sidebarSize"` <= that's wrong.

Comment: By the way you need to use `template: '<p>...</p>'` in your SidebarComponent and not `templateUrl: ''`.

Comment: Yeah I fixed this mistake, still getting the same error, I'm really scratching my head, I can't make a simpler example...

Comment: unfortunately, your plunker is incomplete, and non-functional with 404 errors.  it's not suitable as a [mcve].

Comment: @VincentHarveyCourtois - If my answer below worked for you please consider accepting it as the answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)).

Answer (score 0):

Your plunk is missing a bunch but here is a working plunk with your code in it.

https://plnkr.co/edit/h2yDyjYe6kbUt0t5queO?p=preview

The main takeaways are

1. *(missing)* You need to define a module which contains your components and services that you want to use in the module
2. `templateUrl` should have been `template`

---

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, SidebarComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```